# WHMCS Hook for pin generation

Tags: php, smarty, whmcs

I am using below code to generate support pin in client area  :

```
use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;
add_hook('ClientAreaPrimarySidebar', 1, function (MenuItem $primarySidebar)
{
   $clientID = intval($_SESSION['uid']);
   $SupportPIN = date("dm".$clientID."y");
   $firstSidebar = $primarySidebar->getFirstChild();
   if ($firstSidebar) {
       $firstSidebar->setBodyHtml($SupportPIN);
   }
});
```

This code generate code using date year and customer id.

How can I generate random 8 digit code using whmcs hook ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to generate a supportpin with numeric month, day and afterwards the year? Try doing as the example below:

```
use WHMCS\View\Menu\Item as MenuItem;
add_hook('ClientAreaPrimarySidebar', 1, function (MenuItem $primarySidebar)
{
   $clientID = intval($_SESSION['uid']);
   $SupportPIN = rand(1000, 9999) . rand(1000, 9999);
   $firstSidebar = $primarySidebar->getFirstChild();
if ($firstSidebar) {
$firstSidebar->setBodyHtml($SupportPIN);
   }
});
```

Test results:

`php > rand(1000, 9999) . rand(1000, 9999);
12928206`

Hope that this is what you wanted.

Comment: If this works for you, please accept my answer as true.